# In a measure space show $|\mu(A) - \mu(B)| \leq \mu(A\Delta B)$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ a measure space, and $A, B \in \mathcal{B}$. Show
> $$|\mu(A) - \mu(B)| \leq \mu(A\Delta B)$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

I have to use the symmetric difference  $ A\Delta B = (A\cup B)+(A\cap B)$ then

$$A\Delta B = (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A).$$

Since $A \subseteq (A \Delta B) \cup B$, by (sub)additivity and monotonicity of a measure it follows that

$$\mu(A) \leq \mu(A \Delta B) + \mu(B), $$

and analogously

$$ \mu(B) \leq \mu(A \Delta B) + \mu(A). $$

But I do not how to write step by step.

Comment: What you wrote is already a complete proof (assuming the different $\mu(A) - \mu(B)$ is defined).

Answer (score 3):

You have to assume that $\mu$ is a finite measure since $\mu(A)-\mu(B)$ may not even be defined otherwise.

$$|\mu (A)-\mu(B)|=|[\mu (A \cap B)+\mu (A\setminus B)]-[\mu (A \cap B)+\mu (B\setminus A)]|$$ $$=|\mu(A\setminus B))-\mu(A\setminus B)|\leq \mu(A\setminus B))+\mu(B\setminus A)=\mu (A \Delta B)$$

Answer (score 1):

According to the finite additivity property of measures, it results that

\begin{align*}
\mu(A\Delta B) & = \mu((A - B)\cup(B-A))\\\\
& = \mu((A\cap B^{c})\cup(B\cap A^{c}))\\\\
& = \mu(A\cap B^{c}) + \mu(B\cap A^{c})\\\\
& = \mu(A) - \mu(A\cap B) + \mu(B) - \mu(A\cap B)\\\\
& = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - 2\mu(A\cap B)
\end{align*}

Suppose that $\mu(A) \geq \mu(B)$. Then $|\mu(A) - \mu(B)| = \mu(A) - \mu(B)$.

Consequently, we have that
\begin{align*}
\mu(A\Delta B) - |\mu(A) - \mu(B)| & = \mu(A\Delta B) - \mu(A) + \mu(B)\\\\
& = 2\mu(B) - 2\mu(A\cap B)\\\\
& = 2(\mu(B) - \mu(A\cap B)) \geq0
\end{align*}
where the last relation results from the monotonicity of the measure $\mu$:

\begin{align*}
A\cap B\subseteq B \Rightarrow \mu(A\cap B) \leq \mu(B)
\end{align*}

Similarly, if $\mu(B)\geq \mu(A)$, then we have that

\begin{align*}
\mu(A\Delta B) - |\mu(A) - \mu(B)| & = \mu(A\Delta B) + \mu(A) - \mu(B)\\\\
& = 2\mu(A) - 2\mu(A\cap B)\\\\
& = 2(\mu(A) - \mu(A\cap B)) \geq0
\end{align*}

Hence we conclude that $\mu(A\Delta B) \geq |\mu(A) - \mu(B)|$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: thank you very much, it was very helpful

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

$(A\setminus B)$ and B are disjoint which implies that
$\mu((A\setminus B) \cup B)) = \mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B)$ so we have

$\mu(A \cup B) - \mu(B) = \mu(A\setminus B)$.

Similarly

$\mu(A \cup B) - \mu(A) = \mu(B\setminus A)$.

Which yields that

$2\mu(A \cup B) - \mu(A) - \mu(B) = \mu(A\setminus B) + \mu(B\setminus A)$.

Now the RHS is the symmetric difference and for the LHS note that

$2\mu(A \cup B) \geq 2\mu(A)$.

And similarly for B.